# Node.js with Express fails to connect to MongoDb - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

If I don't start a connection to mongo on port 27017 via mongod in my console, when I try starting my Express server I get the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1000:19)
```

If do I connect via mongod in another shell, and then run node app.js, it works just fine.

```
//app.js

var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res){        

        res.send("Hello, World!")
        global.db.close();
    });

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nvps', function (err , database) {
    if(err) throw err;

    global.db = database;

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('Express server started on port 3000');
    });
});
```

Why doesn't the mongo connection get initiated when I go to http://localhost:3000/ on my machine?

Comment: Are you asking why it throws that error when it *isn't* running? mongod ***has*** to be running to be accessible by node. Why would you expect it to work without it?

Comment: @laggingreflex I thought that it would initiate the connection when accessed through http://localhost.  Is that not the case?  Am I just mis understanding how this works?

Comment: yes, you're misunderstanding. It would initiate the connection but a connection to what? mongod has to be running to process that connection. It's like if your browser could request a page or initiate a connection but unless there's a server running that request is futile. mongod is the server (database server) in this case and your node app is the client.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @laggingreflex.  Obviously I'm pretty new to this!